Boot with pfSense on a HP without screen, and with serial port
I'm trying to boot on a HP PC with an unidentified OS with a pfSense installation key.
I don't have any monitors, and I'm using a Macbook Pro M1.
I have downloaded the AMD64 Memstick USB image and written it into a USB stick with Balena Etcher.
When I start the computer with the USB stick plugged in and with a serial connection from my Mac and to the computer, nothing appears. Impossible to boot to the USB stick and etablish a connection.
In the console, there is only one line where I can write and and enter chars. But I cannot erase any char.
